# Functional Breadth First Search in Scala with the State Monad

Tags: scala, functional-programming, breadth-first-search, state-monad

I'm trying to implement a functional Breadth First Search in Scala to compute the distances between a given node and all the other nodes in an unweighted graph. I've used a State Monad for this with the signature as :-

```
case class State[S,A](run:S => (A,S))
```

Other functions such as map, flatMap, sequence, modify etc etc are similar to what you'd find inside a standard State Monad.

Here's the code :-

```
case class Node(label: Int)

case class BfsState(q: Queue[Node], nodesList: List[Node], discovered: Set[Node], distanceFromSrc: Map[Node, Int]) {
  val isTerminated = q.isEmpty
}

case class Graph(adjList: Map[Node, List[Node]]) {
  def bfs(src: Node): (List[Node], Map[Node, Int]) = {
    val initialBfsState = BfsState(Queue(src), List(src), Set(src), Map(src -> 0))
    val output = bfsComp(initialBfsState)
    (output.nodesList,output.distanceFromSrc)
  }

  @tailrec
  private def bfsComp(currState:BfsState): BfsState = {
     if (currState.isTerminated) currState
     else bfsComp(searchNode.run(currState)._2)
  }

  private def searchNode: State[BfsState, Unit] = for {
    node <- State[BfsState, Node](s => {
      val (n, newQ) = s.q.dequeue
      (n, s.copy(q = newQ))
    })
    s <- get
    _ <- sequence(adjList(node).filter(!s.discovered(_)).map(n => {
      modify[BfsState](s => {
        s.copy(s.q.enqueue(n), n :: s.nodesList, s.discovered + n, s.distanceFromSrc + (n -> (s.distanceFromSrc(node) + 1)))
      })
    }))
  } yield ()
}
```

Please can you advice on :-

1. Should the State Transition on dequeue in the `searchNode` function be a member of `BfsState` itself?
2. How do I make this code more performant/concise/readable?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I suggest moving all the `private def`s related to `bfs` into `bfs` itself. This is the convention for methods that are solely used to implement another.

Second, I suggest simply not using `State` for this matter. `State` (like most monads) is about composition. It is useful when you have many things that all need access to the same global state. In this case, `BfsState` is specialized to `bfs`, will likely never be used anywhere else (it might be a good idea to move the class into `bfs` too), and the `State` itself is always `run`, so the outer world never sees it. (In many cases, this is fine, but here the scope is too small for `State` to be useful.) It'd be much cleaner to pull the logic of `searchNode` into `bfsComp` itself.

Third, I don't understand why you need both `nodesList` and `discovered`, when you can just call `_.toList` on `discovered` once you've done your computation. I've left it in in my reimplementation, though, in case there's more to this code that you haven't displayed.

```
def bfsComp(old: BfsState): BfsState = {
  if(old.q.isEmpty) old // You don't need isTerminated, I think
  else {
    val (currNode, newQ) = old.q.dequeue
    val newState = old.copy(q = newQ)
    adjList(curNode)
      .filterNot(s.discovered) // Set[T] <: T => Boolean and filterNot means you don't need to write !s.discovered(_)
      .foldLeft(newState) { case (BfsState(q, nodes, discovered, distance), adjNode) =>
        BfsState(
          q.enqueue(adjNode),
          adjNode :: nodes,
          discovered + adjNode,
          distance + (adjNode -> (distance(currNode) + 1)
        )
      }
  }
}

def bfs(src: Node): (List[Node], Map[Node, Int]) = {
  // I suggest moving BfsState and bfsComp into this method
  val output = bfsComp(BfsState(Queue(src), List(src), Set(src), Map(src -> 0)))
  (output.nodesList, output.distanceFromSrc)
  // Could get rid of nodesList and say output.discovered.toList
}
```

In the event that you think you *do* have a good reason for using `State` here, here are my thoughts.
You use `def searchNode`. The point of a `State` is that it is pure and immutable, so it should be a `val`, or else you reconstruct the same `State` every use.

You write:

```
node <- State[BfsState, Node](s => {
  val (n, newQ) = s.q.dequeue
  (n, s.copy(q = newQ))
})
```

First off, Scala's syntax was designed so that you don't need to have both a `()` and `{}` surrounding an anonymous function:

```
node <- State[BfsState, Node] { s =>
  // ...
}
```

Second, this doesn't look *quite* right to me. One benefit of using for-syntax is that the anonymous functions are hidden from you and there is minimal indentation. I'd just write it out

```
oldState <- get
(node, newQ) = oldState.q.dequeue
newState = oldState.copy(q = newQ)
```

Footnote: would it make sense to make `Node` an inner class of `Graph`? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and brilliant answer. I am refactoring code accordingly. Just one question 

1.) Could you elaborate a bit more on why the State Monad isn't a good idea here and  give some examples where you think it is a good idea ?

Comment: `State` isn't very useful here because it isn't used very much. There is only one real value of `State` in this case, and the complexity added by using `State` is simply greater than than the benefit it provides. If you were doing something more complicated, `State` would be more useful, but here, it is not.